# Azure service Bus geo-recovery automation using az bash commands

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-cli, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

In MS docs for AzureCLI, we couldn't find, az command to do perform the Switchover activity from our primary Service Bus to the Secondary Service Bus.

We are performing, below activities as part of the switchover and couldn't find the required AZ commands to fulfill our requirements.

Task 1. Re-initiate the Pairing with secondary namespace (for which the alias already present, for which we already have the alias created). Here we cold find only to create a new paring , but not with existing.

```
az servicebus georecovery-alias create --alias <prim-second-existing alias-name> --namespace-name <primary-sb-namespace-name> --partner-namespace <secondary-sb-namespace-name>  --resource-group <primary-sb-namespace-RGName>
```

Perform Failover:-

```
az servicebus georecovery-alias fail-over <prim-second-existing alias-name> --ids <secondary-sb-namespace-name>  --is-safe-failover y -namespace-name <primary-sb-namespace-name> --resource-group <primary-sb-namespace-RGName>
```

task3:- Once Failover done, Delete Ques and topics from the Primary-SB-instance Namespace. Here how to find the pending ques and topics in the primary instance to set it for deletion

```
    az servicebus topic delete --ids pending-TopicIds --name yyyy --namespace-name <primary-sb-namespace-name> --resource-group <primary-sb-namespace-RGName> --subscription ssssss
```

For ques

```
    az servicebus queue delete --ids pending-queids --name que-name --namespace-name <primary-sb-namespace-name> --resource-group <primary-sb-namespace-RGName> --subscription ssssssss
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking up the pair and reinitiate again with [`az servicebus georecovery-alias break-pair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/georecovery-alias?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-georecovery-alias-break-pair) @Vowneee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure service Bus geo-recovery automation using AZ bash commands:

Firstly, I have created an alias for disaster recovery configuration of a service bus namespace with the partner namespace as shown below.

[image]

Now before reinitiating the pair, use [`az servicebus georecovery-alias break-pair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/georecovery-alias?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-georecovery-alias-break-pair) bash command to disable the disaster recovery existed alias configuration for avoiding conflicts.

```bash
az servicebus georecovery-alias break-pair --alias newaliaas --namespace-name bus1jah --resource-group xxxx
```

[image]

Once it is disabled, now again set it with the new alias or the same alias with the `az servicebus georecovery-alias set` as shown.

```bash
 az servicebus georecovery-alias set --resource-group xxxx --namespace-name bus1jah --alias newaliaas --partner-namespace <ResourceID of partner service bus namespace>
```

[image]

*Note:*

If you wanted to check the existed or recently created alias under a service bus namespace, use below command to list it out.

```bash
az servicebus georecovery-alias list --namespace-name bus1jah --resource-group xxxx
```

Now you can go ahead with the other tasks like fail over as well as deleting the topics or queues according to your requirement with the corresponding commands.

```bash
az servicebus georecovery-alias fail-over --alias newaliaas --namespace-name bus2new --resource-group xxxx
```

`az servicebus queue delete`

[image]

Refer MS Doc for Az bash commands [`az servicebus georecovery-alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/georecovery-alias?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: But here the failover command bit confusing..

Comment: But here the failover command bit confusing.. "az servicebus georecovery-alias fail-over --alias xxxx --ids xxxxxx --is-safe-failover y --namespace-name xxxxxx --resource-group --subscription ". here id , namespace, RG, subscription etc are belongs to primary instance or secondary insatnce?

Comment: --name is `primary-second-existing alias-name` --namespace-name is `secondary-service bus-namespace-name` --resource-group xx. @Vowneee

Comment: Thanks.. so the --id is optional and , RG and Subscription is of secondary instance here?

Comment: Yes correct. @Vowneee